# Is it true that any 3-regular graph containing K_{3,2} as subgraph must be non-planar?

Tags: graph-theory

It might seem intuitively clear once we try to draw down such a graph. But I cannot figure out a formal proof by applying Kuratowski's theorem yet. I am aware that the construction of 3-regular bipartite graph is a mysterious hard problem. See https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00990486/document.

Comment: The article you share is about generating **all** $3$-regular graphs, in an **optimal** time. You don't need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
The following graph is $3$-regular, with a $K_{2,3}$ subgraph, and planar. I found it starting with $K_{2,3}$ and making it $3$-regular.
[image]

Even better, the following graph is $3$-regular, planar, and with $K_{2,3}$ as an **induced** subgraph.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I realized that what I asked is not really what I had in mind. Let me ask a new question again.

Comment: Here might be a true conjecture this time: Is it true that any 3-regular bipartite graph containing K_{3,2} as subgraph must be non-planar? Why?

Comment: By the way, I am a little bit confused why the first example $K_{2,3}$ is not an **induced** subgraph.

Comment: @AustenFAN The induced subgraph would also contain the grey edge in the red component, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph.

Comment: @AustenFAN Also, have you given your conjecture some thought? Have you searched for literature, tried some small examples or counterexamples?

Comment: @Servaes Thanks for your answer. However, I am still confused why the property of whether containing $K_{2,3}$ as an induced subgraph is different. If we take 1,2,A,B,C in the upper graph, it trivially contains $K_{2,3}$ as an induced subgraph. If we take 1,2,A,B,C along with vertices inside the red graph in the below graph, we still don't get a 3-regular graph.

Comment: @AustenFAN Check the definition of *induced* subgraph again. The induced subgraph on these vertices is not $K_{2,3}$.

Comment: @Servaes I see now. Thanks!